# Django join-like query with no where condition

Tags: python, django, join

Say I have 3 models in Django

```
class Instrument(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, db_index=True)

class Instrument_df(models.Model):
    instrument = models.OneToOneField(
        Instrument,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )

class Quote(models.Model):
    instrument = models.ForeignKey(Instrument, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I just want to query all Quotes that correspond to an instrument of 'DF' type. in SQL I would perform the join of Quote and Instrument_df on field id.

Using Django's ORM I came out with

```
Quote.objects.filter(instrument__instrument_df__instrument_id__gte=-1)
```

I think this does the job, but  I see two drawbacks:

1) I am joining 3 tables, when in fact table Instrument would not need to be involved.

2) I had to insert the trivial id > -1 condition, that holds always. This looks awfully artificial.

How should this query be written?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any other field in `Instrument_df` ? If no, your model seems wrong...

Comment: @bruno There are, indeed, I just removed everything else and kept the references among those models. Sorry for not clarifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Instrument_df` has other fields not shown in the snippet (else this table is just useless and could be replaced by a flag in `Instrument`), a possible solution could be to use either a subquery or two queries:

```
# with a subquery
dfids = Instrument_df.objects.values_list("instrument", flat=True)
Quote.objects.filter(instrument__in=dfids)

# with two queries (can be faster on MySQL)
dfids = list(Instrument_df.objects.values_list("instrument", flat=True))
Quote.objects.filter(instrument__in=dfids)
```

Whether this will perform better than your actual solution depends on your db vendor and version (MySQL was known for being very bad at handling subqueries, don't know if it's still the case) and actual content.

**But** I think the best solution here would be a plain [raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/) - this is a bit less portable and may require more care in case of a schema update (hint: use a custom manager and write this query as a manager method so you have one single point of truth - you don't want to scatter your views with raw sql queries).

Comment: Thank you, @bruno. I understand your solutions, I had had similar ideas but thought there should be a simpler single-query solution. I am a newbie in database ORMs, so far they seem to me trickier than I expected.

Comment: Well, using a raw query IS a "single-query solution". wrt/ ORMs, Django's has been designed to make the 80% simple cases easy, and leave you with either not-so-trivial solutions and raw queries for the more complex cases. Some other ORMs try to be as complete as possible to cover 100% use cases - technically reimplementing the whole SQL language as Python objects - but end up being practically at least twice more complicated to use for the 80% simple cases.